# NMOS Cascode Logic

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cmos, nmos

I have following problem and I ask you ,if possible, any help to resolve it.
[image]

Size the following circuit so that it achieves a 100 ps delay (50-50) using 0.25 μm devices, while driving a 100 fF load on both differential outputs. (VDD = 2.5V) Assume A, B and their complements are available as inputs.
Other data available for NMOS are following
Vt=0.43(V),Vdsat=0.63(V),k'=115x10^-6 (A/V^2),lambda=0.06(v^-1)

I tried to compute current charge/discharge Ic=C*dv/dt with dv/dt=(vdd/2)/T con T=100ps and Vdd=2.5V ,because current on two series NMOS ( I call it In) depends by W/L then setting In=Ic and solving for W/L I get W for a specific L...in this case L=0.25u beacuse tecnology is 250nm.How can I compute current in NMOS series?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. You need to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show us all of your work, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Ok,I tried to compute current charge/discharge Ic=C*dv/dt  with dv/dt=(vdd/2)/T con T=100ps and Vdd=2.5V  ,because current on two series NMOS ( I call it In) depends by W/L then setting In=Ic and solving for W/L I get W for a specific L...in this case L=0.25u beacuse tecnology is 250nm....the problem is...what is equation for NMOS series In?all nmos will be same W? moreover what is the funcion of two inverter) (I suppose inverters acts as memory element)...what do you think?

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. It is not a forum. -- Please [edit] your question to add new information. Down here in the comments it will be overlooked.